# How to display Parent Title "and" parent's children using WP_list_pages

Tags: wordpress

I am outputting a list of children menu options in WordPress which I'm able to do successfully using wp_list_pages('child_of = 91');.

91 is the ID of the parent whose children I'm outputting. However, I'd like to display the actual name of the parent as well and not just the children. I can McGuyver the scenario if I had to, but I'd like to learn how to do it properly :)

Thanks in advance for the help.

D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried something like this?

`wp_list_pages('child_of = 91&title_li=&include='.$post->post_parent);`

Comment: Hey Wickywills, thanks for the answer. That worked great. As a quick note, there was an extra quote mark after the word "post_parent". Thx again!